# Footnote separator

Tags: footnotes, rules

How can I remove the separator line between the footnotes and the text?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
\renewcommand*\footnoterule{}
```

Answer (score 8):

Another option is `\usepackage[norule]{footmisc}`.

(One may also want to use the `bottom` option of the [footmisc](http://ctan.org/pkg/footmisc) package -- this will place footnotes *below* bottom floats, contrary to LaTeX's default behaviour.)

EDIT: If you're using a [KOMA-script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) class, yet another option is `\setfootnoterule{0pt}`. (The command syntax is `\setfootnoterule[<height>]{<length>}`; the command was added in KOMA-script v3.06.)

Comment: `setfootnoterule{0pt}` has no effect when loading the KOMA-script package `scrextend`.