# Using \thanks and \footnote without without numbering/mark and line

Tags: footnotes

I want to use `\thanks` and `\footnote` without any numbering/mark with my title. Is there a way to do it?

I use:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twocolumn,10pt]{article}
```

after Alan Munn's answer it works for the numbering or mark, but what about the line just above the footnote?

Comment: Which document class are you using? Adding a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would clarify such things and allow other people to modify it accordantly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As the comments suggest, there may be some issues with the particular document class you are using, but with the regular `article` or `scrartcl` classes (but not with classes that create a title page) you can simply redefine `\footnotemark` in your preamble.  This won't affect the further use of footnotes in the document (which I assume you still want to have numbered normally.)  I've also added code to remove the footnote rule.

```
\documentclass{article}
\author{An Author}
\title{A title\thanks{Some thanks}}
\renewcommand\footnotemark{}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Some text\footnote{Hello}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @berkay: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3592/footnote-separator

Comment: @Caramdir I've added that code. That will remove the rule for all subsequent footnotes too.  To do it on just the first page (if that's what's needed) is tricky without an explicit `\clearpage`, I think.

Comment: I could use more explanation of what this solution is doing. I see no reason this should remove footnote marks for thanks but not for other footnotes. What is going on here?

Comment: @RandyCragun The `\thanks` command is basically `\footnote` but with a symbol instead of a number. The `\maketitle` command uses that and then resets the footnote counter to 0 and the counter to numeric so that regular footnotes work properly. This resetting is independent of what changes happened earlier, including the change that I've added to remove the footnote mark.