# Footnote with fancyfoot

Tags: header-footer, footnotes, fancyhdr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Footnote separator](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3592/footnote-separator)

I'm using fancyhdr as a package and have defined the following:

```
\fancyfoot[LE]{\psboxit{box 0.8 setgray fill}
{\framebox[10mm][c]{\rule{0cm}{4mm}\color{black}{\bfseries \thepage}}}}
%% odd side pages
\fancyfoot[RO]{\psboxit{box 1 setgray fill}
{\hspace{\textwidth}\psboxit{box 0.8 setgray fill}
{\framebox[10mm][c]{\rule{0cm}{4mm}\color{black}{\bfseries \thepage}}}}}
```

The result is something like this:

[image]

My question is the following: Is there any way to be able to add footnotes on that line?

If you include a footnote the traditional way it will generate a new line which will appear above line footer line.

Comment: I think the question is more: can you remove the line above the footnotes? The answer is there: [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3592/5526).

Comment: The solution here looks the same as the linked question, so I'm going to close as a duplicate.