# How do I remove this line from the bottom of the page?

Tags: line

[image]    % $Id: template.tex 11 2007-04-03 22:25:53Z jpeltier $

```
\documentclass{vgtc}                          % final (conference style)
%\documentclass[review]{vgtc}                 % review
%\documentclass[widereview]{vgtc}             % wide-spaced review
%\documentclass[preprint]{vgtc}               % preprint
%\documentclass[electronic]{vgtc}             % electronic version

%% Uncomment one of the lines above depending on where your paper is
%% in the conference process. ``review'' and ``widereview'' are for review
%% submission, ``preprint'' is for pre-publication, and the final version
%% doesn't use a specific qualifier. Further, ``electronic'' includes
%% hyperreferences for more convenient online viewing.

%% Please use one of the ``review'' options in combination with the
%% assigned online id (see below) ONLY if your paper uses a double blind
%% review process. Some conferences, like IEEE Vis and InfoVis, have NOT
%% in the past.

%% Figures should be in CMYK or Grey scale format, otherwise, colour 
%% shifting may occur during the printing process.

%% These few lines make a distinction between latex and pdflatex calls and they
%% bring in essential packages for graphics and font handling.
%% Note that due to the \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{} call it is no longer necessary
%% to provide the the path and extension of a graphics file:
%% \includegraphics{diamondrule} is completely sufficient.
%%
\ifpdf%                                % if we use pdflatex
  \pdfoutput=1\relax                   % create PDFs from pdfLaTeX
  \pdfcompresslevel=9                  % PDF Compression
  \pdfoptionpdfminorversion=7          % create PDF 1.7
  \ExecuteOptions{pdftex}
  \usepackage{graphicx}                % allow us to embed graphics files
  \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg,.jpeg} % for pdflatex we expect .pdf, .png, or .jpg files
\else%                                 % else we use pure latex
  \ExecuteOptions{dvips}
  \usepackage{graphicx}                % allow us to embed graphics files
  \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}     % for pure latex we expect eps files
\fi%

%% it is recomended to use ``\autoref{sec:bla}'' instead of ``Fig.~\ref{sec:bla}''
\graphicspath{{figures/}{pictures/}{images/}{./}} % where to search for the images

\usepackage{microtype}                 % use micro-typography (slightly more compact, better to read)
\PassOptionsToPackage{warn}{textcomp}  % to address font issues with \textrightarrow
\usepackage{textcomp}                  % use better special symbols
\usepackage{mathptmx}                  % use matching math font
\usepackage{times}                     % we use Times as the main font
\renewcommand*\ttdefault{txtt}         % a nicer typewriter font
\usepackage{cite}                      % needed to automatically sort the references
\usepackage{tabu}                      % only used for the table example
\usepackage{booktabs}                  % only used for the table example
%% We encourage the use of mathptmx for consistent usage of times font
%% throughout the proceedings. However, if you encounter conflicts
%% with other math-related packages, you may want to disable it.


%% If you are submitting a paper to a conference for review with a double
%% blind reviewing process, please replace the value ``0'' below with your
%% OnlineID. Otherwise, you may safely leave it at ``0''.
\onlineid{0}

%% declare the category of your paper, only shown in review mode
\vgtccategory{Research}

%% allow for this line if you want the electronic option to work properly

%% In preprint mode you may define your own headline.
%\preprinttext{To appear in an IEEE VGTC sponsored conference.}

%% Paper title.

\title{Global Illumination for Fun and Profit}

%% This is how authors are specified in the conference style

%% Author and Affiliation (single author).
%%\author{Roy G. Biv\thanks{e-mail: roy.g.biv@aol.com}}
%%\affiliation{\scriptsize Allied Widgets Research}

%% Author and Affiliation (multiple authors with single affiliations).
%%\author{Roy G. Biv\thanks{e-mail: roy.g.biv@aol.com} %
%%\and Ed Grimley\thanks{e-mail:ed.grimley@aol.com} %
%%\and Martha Stewart\thanks{e-mail:martha.stewart@marthastewart.com}}
%%\affiliation{\scriptsize Martha Stewart Enterprises \\ Microsoft Research}
%% Author and Affiliation (multiple authors with multiple affiliations)
\author{Roy G. Biv\thanks{e-mail: roy.g.biv@aol.com}\\ %
        \scriptsize Starbucks Research %
\and Ed Grimley\thanks{e-mail:ed.grimley@aol.com}\\ %
     \scriptsize Grimley Widgets, Inc. %
\and Martha Stewart\thanks{e-mail:martha.stewart@marthastewart.com}\\ %
     \parbox{1.4in}{\scriptsize \centering Martha Stewart Enterprises \\ Microsoft Research}}



%% A teaser figure can be included as follows, but is not recommended since
%% the space is now taken up by a full width abstract.
%\teaser{
%  \includegraphics[width=1.5in]{sample.eps}
%  \caption{Lookit! Lookit!}
%}


%% ACM Computing Classification System (CCS). 
%% See <http://www.acm.org/class/1998/> for details.
%% The ``\CCScat'' command takes four arguments.



%% Copyright space is enabled by default as required by guidelines.
%% It is disabled by the 'review' option or via the following command:
% \nocopyrightspace

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% START OF THE PAPER %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

%% The ``\maketitle'' command must be the first command after the
%% ``\begin{document}'' command. It prepares and prints the title block.

%% the only exception to this rule is the \firstsection command
 %dmz
\firstsection{Introduction}

\maketitle






%% if specified like this the section will be committed in review mode
\acknowledgments{
The authors wish to thank A, B, C. This work was supported in part by
a grant from XYZ.}

%\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv-doi}
%\bibliographystyle{abbrv-doi-narrow}
%\bibliographystyle{abbrv-doi-hyperref}
%\bibliographystyle{abbrv-doi-hyperref-narrow}

\bibliography{template}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the documentclass available from somewhere?

Comment: Not tested because I cannot compile your code, but maybe try https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3592/footnote-separator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line seems to occur due to `\footnoterule{}` and you can remove it all together if you include

```
\renewcommand*\footnoterule{}
```

in your preamble